# How to register a custom UserGroupCallback for kjar deployed to jbpm console

Tags: jbpm

I am working with JBPM 6.2. The plan is to deploy kjars to a common runtime of the jbpm console and use the REST API inside an application webapp to move through the process. We have successfully built kjars and deployed them to the jbpm console. We are able to move go through a basic workflow if the user tasks are assigned to a specific users instead of groups.

We have a class that implement UserGroupCallback inside the kjar; however, the runtime seems to ignore the custom call back and uses the JAASUserGroupCallbackImpl. Is there some way to register the callback with the remote runtime?